# Styling input type="file" - no "No file selected" appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I've recently decided to try styling a `input type="file"`.
The design works almost fine, the only problem is that I want the text "No file selected" appear in the `filename` selection. Even when I select a file no text does appear.
I would appreciate any help and explanations!

I have the following code: `HTML`

```
<div class="fileuploader">
  <input type="text" class="filename" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="button" name="file" class="filebutton" value="Browse" />
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</div>
```

and following `CSS`

```
.fileuploader {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.filename {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0 none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 302px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #777;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}


    .filebutton {
        float: left;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        outline: 0 none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff inset;
        color: #555555;
        margin-left: 3px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        background: #DDDDDD;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE 0%, #DDDDDD 100%);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #EEEEEE), color-stop(100%, #DDDDDD));filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#EEEEEE', endColorstr='#DDDDDD', GradientType=0);
    }

    .fileuploader input[type=file] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border: 0;
        height: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        -khtml-opacity: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Best of luck to you on this one. Styling a file input, and having it work consistently on different browsers and operating systems is a giant pain. If you do resolve this in your current browser/OS (Mac Safari? I think that does the "No file selected" thing if I remember), make sure you test it thoroughly in all major combinations.

Comment: @JoeEnos Actually Firefox 22.0, don't you maybe have an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Nope, I tried styling a file upload control once, and gave up because of issues like this - browsers are super sensitive about this control, for security purposes. Unfortunately, that means they all have their own styling challenges as well, so I just said screw it, and found 3rd party alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the text "No file selected" appear in the filename selection.
>   Even when I select a file no text does appear.

One solution would be to update the filename whenever the file input fires a JavaScript 'change' event. This can easily be accomplished using jQuery's $.change() function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
        var val = ($(this).val()) ? $(this).val() : "No file selected.";
        $('.filename').attr('placeholder', val);
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

I've created a jsFiddle that includes this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/cfY6m/1/

Comment: Not a problem! I'm glad you found it helpful!